# In spoken, is 'with' droppable in "I won't let you through with this"

Tags: spoken-english

> I won't let you through with this.

I've heard the sentence in an American TV show. The scene is in a security check point. A man carried something that was suspected to be a bomb, so the security staff said it.

But to my ear, the guy who said the sentence didn't seem to pronounce the word 'with'. It sounds much like:

> I won't let you through this.

So, I'm wondering if the 'with' is droppable in spoken?

By the way, the man probably spoke the African American English, but I'm not exactly sure.

Comment: Is there a video clip of this scene available online?

Comment: @ThePhoton I'll try to find it later, but I'm not sure if I could be able to.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the speaker actually wants to say.

> A. I won't let you through with this.

You can break (A) down like this:

> I won't let you [go] **through** [this metal door] with **this** (= the bomb/briefcase/belt).

Compare this with

> I am sorry sir, but I can't let you enter the building with that gun.

The speaker could also have meant this:

> B. I won't let you through this.

You can break (B) down like this:

> I won't let you through **this** (= the metal door/check point).

Comment: Interesting, but the subtitle is written as: "I won't let you through with this." But I didn't hear 'with' indeed.

Comment: Well, transcriptions can be incorrect sometimes. But both versions are valid depending on the context or the intended meaning.

Comment: @dan, "with this" might be shorted to "w'this" but the 'w' shouldn't be completely dropped.

Answer (score 1):

"With" is often not stressed. And especially when followed by a word beginning in "th" it may be shortened.

But the *w* sound (at least an exhalation of breath) should not be fully dropped, and in writing we wouldn't omit the "with".